# How to make a keyboard long press delete function?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a customized `UIInputView` for a `UITextField`.

For a normal keyboard, when press delete button one character is deleted. If long press, then keep deleting. I want to making the same effect of it. But the long press didn't work as expected.

What I tried is:

(1) Added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` into the delete button.

(2) Added the action.

```
@IBAction func longPressDelete(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {    
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.4, repeats: true) { timer in
                    switch sender.state {
                        case .began:
                            break
                        case .ended, .cancelled, .failed:
                            timer.invalidate()
                        default:
                            timer.invalidate()
                    }
                    self.deleteKeyPress?() //callback for delete one character called once.
                }
            }
```

The effect isn't as good as the iOS normal keyboard. More importantly there's an error

```
[KeyboardTaskQueue] -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue lockWhenReadyForMainThread] timeout waiting for task on queue
```

And you have to release your figure and press again for deleting works again.

Any idea what's the issue? thanks!

**EDIT**
By passing the `UITextField` into the customized UIView and call the methods `deleteBackward()` in `UIKeyInput` solved the issue.